# Rspec; verifying an element state when the attribute that doesn't have a value

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, attributes, watir

I am doing some automation testing using Rspec and Watir. 
What I currently would like to do is verify the presence of a button element's attribute titled `hidden`.  So in pseudo-code I would like to do this:

```
Find button element; press click
Verify button element now has another attribute titled "hidden"
perform further actions
```

Is it possible to find attributes of this nature, or do they always need to say something like `hidden=hidden`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`hidden?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/HTMLElement#hidden%3F-instance_method) method:

```
<input type="submit" value="button">
browser.button.hidden?
#=> false

<input type="submit" value="button" hidden>
browser.button.hidden?
#=> true
```

Then, you can create an rspec example that uses an [expectation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers) to validate:

```
describe "Button" do
  it "should be hidden" do
    expect(browser.button.hidden?).to be true
  end
end
```

And `expect(browser.button.hidden?).to be true` is clunky.  As Justin Ko astutely points out, rspec provides some syntactic sugar in the form of predicate matchers to make it cleaner: `expect(browser.button).to be_hidden`.

Comment: For RSpec, a [predicate matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers) might be nicer - `expect(browser.button).to be_hidden`

Comment: @Justin Ko: Good call.  Was trying to keep it simple.  I've updated with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, this works--I will need to do some refactoring to take advantage of the syntactic sugar, but overall #hidden? works!